# How to add new classes to tensorflow.js model in transfer learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js, transfer-learning

have a pre-trained network that can object detect one class. How do I add more classes to this model without losing the previous knowledge of that original class?

I have read in another post that suggests creating a new model, with the "base model" layers except for the last two layers. (Why the last 2 specifically?). and setting the new model last 2 layers weights to the base model's last 2 layers weights. Link to Post: How to add a new category to a deep learning model

```
weights_training = base_model.layers[-2].get_weights()
new_model.layers[-2].set_weights(weights_training)
```

note that the above code is in tensorflow not tfjs.

Would I be able to do the same in tensorflow.js?

Comment: Do you mean transfer learning? For determining which layers to remove its not always the last 2 layers instead it depends on the very last layer before the flatten operation. This layer is called the "bottleneck layer". The bottleneck layer features retain more generality as compared to the final/top layer. You need to replace it with a classification head that fits for your problem.

Comment: Yes, in transfer learning. the last layer before the flatten operation. Where do you get your resources for transfer learning? Thank you!

Comment: @yuRa how would I be able to tell which layer is the bottleneck layer?